# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

Actually, I am trying upload file on the server and for that, I have written a `handleDocumentChange` function for file upload the when I upload the document then show

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Here my code:

handleDocumentChangle

```
handleDocumentChange = (e, name) => {
  let { StudentID } = this.state;
  console.log("STID", StudentID);
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("document", e.target.files[0]);
  form.append("title", e.target.name);
  http
    .post(`fupload/${StudentID}`, form)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

input box

```
<CardContent className={classes.docName}>
  <Typography variant="body1" component="h2">
    Photograph
    <input
      name="photograph"
      accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/pdf"
      type="file"
      onChange={e => this.handleDocumentChange("photograph", e)}
      style={{ display: "none" }}
      ref="photograph"
    />
  </Typography>
</CardContent>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the parameter order like this make the **e** as first parameter because your function is waiting **e** as First Parameter

```
<CardContent className={classes.docName}>
                      <Typography variant="body1" component="h2">
                        Photograph
                        <input
                          name="photograph"
                          accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/pdf"
                          type="file"
                          onChange={e =>
                            this.handleDocumentChange(e,"photograph")
                          }
                          style={{ display: "none" }}
                          ref="photograph"
                        />
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your function parameters. In handleDocumentChange you expect first parameter to be the event and second name, but when calling the function, your first parameter is the name and second is the event.